# find text from transaction message with blockfrost or koios

Tags: transaction, blockfrost, message-signing

small (maybe) easy question.

i want to find with blockfrost a "message" on a transaction.

can someone help me a bit for this? i dont find currently anything.

thank you in advanced.
TTS17

Comment: By `"message" on a transaction` do you mean finding transaction metadata given a transaction hash? There is [this Blockfrost resource](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/~1txs~1{hash}~1metadata/get) or [this Koios resource](https://api.koios.rest/#post-/tx_metadata).

Comment: i think we speak for the same.

https://developers.cardano.org/docs/governance/cardano-improvement-proposals/cip-0020/

i think it is the ""Handling ill-formed 674 metadata""

thank i will do some test with real transactions and message.

i want to ask people to text something specific and when i find transaction with this message, to do something else

Comment: perfect, i found one transaction with msg in cardanoscan and execute this command.  ----- curl -H 'project_id: mainnetID' https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/txs/77486ddc3235ee4097890a99d6bb2cf4d891b86829e860d4a2f3b5f8bd059a24/metadata

Comment: Good to know! I have added an answer after your clarification so feel free to mark it as answered. Don't hesitate to comment asking for more details if you need more info too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the message in your context is the [CIP 20: Transaction message/comment metadata](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/governance/cardano-improvement-proposals/cip-0020/), you can query [this Blockfrost resource](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Transactions/paths/%7E1txs%7E1%7Bhash%7D%7E1metadata/get) or [this Koios resource](https://api.koios.rest/#post-/tx_metadata) to retrieve the metadata of a transaction given its hash, specifically retrieving the details under the `674` label.

Comment: thank you mate, is something i have found with combination of your answer and my research. you have verify and then i test it. is so great what all is possible :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Don't hesitate to add a comment if you have any further related questions.

Comment: thank you,
i will try to use this with BASH and collect a number from there, and then compare it with the APOCH number :)